# Import spreadsheet data into SQL database through MVC application, is there a way to assign values for columns not on the spreadsheet during import?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an MVC application and currently working on being able to import employee data from an Excel spreadsheet. I have 2 non-null columns in the database that are not present in the excel file (employeestatus - bit, and datecreated - datetime).

Is there a way to set values for these columns when importing the others? If I create new columns in the spreadsheet for these fields and add them to the mapping it works perfect, but I want to avoid the client having to do that.

```
                //where data gets stored in db
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Employee";

                //mappings
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "id");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("LastName", "employeelastname");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("FirstName","employeefirstname");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("MI", "employeemi");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("StreetAddress1", "streetaddress");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "employeecity");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("State", "employeestate");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Zip", "employeezip");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Payroll", "payroll");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "salary");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("POBox", "pobox");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("POBoxCity", "poboxcity");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("POBoxState", "poboxstate");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Org", "orgcode");

                //write and close connection
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                excelConnection.Close();
```

Ideally, it'd be like:

```
sqlBulk.ColumnMapping.Set("status", "1");
sqlBulk.ColumnMapping.Set("empdatecreated") = DateTime.Now();
```

My searches are taking me in circles of examples where all the data needed is already in the spreadsheet.

If I put this into a temp table first, could I set the column values for all the rows then?

Thank you

Comment: What is the definition of dReader? My first thought is to modify the thing that drives that so it adds some fake columns with the data you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `dReader` is perhaps a datareader connected via the jet/ace driver to a spreadsheet:

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConnStr);
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You could add the columns you want to that sql so them are available on the reader:

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *, 1 as status, NOW() as empdatecreated FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConnStr);
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to use DATE() instead of NOW(), but using "1 as status, DATE() as empdatecreated" wokred perfect. Thank you so much again!